# Break point not hitting in chrome js fiddle

Tags: google-chrome, jsfiddle

I have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/y20uj7ku/) link.
But my break point is not hitting.

**What I tried is:**

1. [how to debug the js in jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460046/how-to-debug-the-js-in-jsfiddle)
2. [Inspecting javascript on jsfiddle.net in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655058/inspecting-javascript-on-jsfiddle-net-in-google-chrome)

But my `index` file is empty.