# How do I debug javascript in the NEW jsfiddle.net UI using Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jsfiddle

## Edit

**This question got downvoted three times with no explanation.**

To clarify, I have already tried everything at this question:

[Inspecting javascript on jsfiddle.net in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655058/inspecting-javascript-on-jsfiddle-net-in-google-chrome?rq=1)

None of these answers seem to work anymore, as jsfiddle.net has recently heavily updated its UI.

I am looking for an answer with the *new* UI.

I don't seem to be able to debug the javascript in my jsfiddles anymore.

I am unable to find where to look in the "Sources" section of Chrome's developer toolbar in order to set a breakpoint in the actual resultant javascript.

In addition, using `debugger;` no longer works with the new jsfiddle; all I get is this:

[image]

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? Three downvotes and no comments :/

Comment: It's not a "code" question, but it's 100% software development related question

Comment: C'mon guys, it's courtesy to explain a downvote